# Current field of view specific legends in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend, print-composer

Is it possible to make QGIS generate a legend that is based only on the field visible in composer?

There was a ticket marked as resolved five months ago with this question but it doesn't divulge the solution!
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3121

There are other questions appearing to ask this but I can't find the solution within them. A workaround I'm using at the moment is to save a new vector layer based on a selection of the field of view and plotting a legend from that.

Is there must be a more sensible way?

Answer (score 3):

The legend property button 'Filter Legend By Map Content' will update the legend items based on the current visibly geometries in the map composer. Have tested it on polygon layers in QGIS 2.6.

[image]

Comment: Then please close the question by accepting the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow